# Why cant my VS2010 workflow project see the early-bound CRM classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to develop a custom workflow for CRM 2011 on-site.  I followed the MS tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx to the point where the CRM Explorer window of VS shows the Entities etc in CRM and the built workflow project can be deployed from VS and appears in CRM.  However, in the CS code the CRM entities are not known types.  I guess that I have missed a reference.  These are the ones I have:

```
...
namespace TP24408ContactMatch.Workflow   
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
    using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
    ...
```

I suspect that I haven't given anywhere near enough info here, but if anyone has the patience to lead me by the nose I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

There are no early bound entities in the CRM SDK.  You have to [build them using the crmSvcUtil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx).

Comment: Oh.  What was the point of my specifying the CRM instance to connect to when I created the project - I sort-of thought that was supposed to create the classes for you?

Comment: @SimonSellick that just allows you to deploy solutions / plugins / custom workflow activities to CRM